# how to display employees, their salaries and the average for the department?

Tags: sql

I have a table with employees names, salaries and departments id. How can I display their list with name, salary and average salary in employee's department in one table?

e.g.

```
name  | sal  | av. sal.
------+------+--------
Smith | 1500 | 2000
```

Comment: Did you not go to class?

Comment: What do you mean? If the answer is obvious, write it.

Comment: We're not in the habit of doing people's homework for them. If you don't know how to write a SQL select query, you should take a basic SQL tutorial.

Comment: I've just begun to learn SQL. I take a kind of tutorial but I had a problem only with one case. Perhaps it is basic, but everything could be perceived like simple if sb is an expert. It wasnt my homework.

Comment: Show us what you've tried, then. The stuff you're looking for is a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: If it isn't homework are you claiming that this is real work? Are you saying you've been hired to manage a database but can't do this select query?

Comment: It is just a case that I made up to practise.

Comment: I tried: select ename, deptno, avg(sal) from emp group by deptno. The answer very helped me, beceuce I didn't know that I can do such a syntax. Maby I should after finishing the course, but I thought that Stack is mostly for people who learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT name,
       sal,
       avgSal 
FROM Employee e,
     (SELECT deptId,
             avg(sal) as avgSal
      FROM Employee
      group by deptId
     ) avgSalary 
WHERE e.deptId= avgSalary.deptId
```

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: I have tried this and I've got the error: "syntax error at or near "SELECT"" It concern the SELECT in bracket. I use PostgreSQL.

Comment: There should be "ON" instead of "WHERE" and it works.